# Angular. SCSS. Position relative to the container. Wrapping of elements

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have a template:

```
<div class='container>
 <my-comp class='element' 
  styles='style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative;"'>
  Element
 </my-comp >
 <my-comp  class='element' 
  style="left: 150px; top: 0px; position: relative;">
  Element
 </my-comp >
 <my-comp  class='element' 
  style="left: 450px; top: 0px; position: relative;">
  Element
 </my-comp >
</div>
```

I want the components inside the container to wrap one under another when the width of the container is too small to contain them.
With:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

It does wrap but only when original position of element is reached.
I want to be able to manually position all of the elements wherever I want inside the container. Is there any way possible to do it?

Is it possible to do with pure CSS or do I need a service beetwen the container (main components) and children components and subscribe to 'resize' events of the container and position them?